# Customize Colors in Visual Studio

Tags: visual-studio

Is there any way to customize the color of variables in Visual Studio and not change the whole theme.

For example:

[image]

Is it possible to change variable's color to be easier to read in the dark theme?

Comment: Check these: https://devblogs.microsoft.com/visualstudio/custom-themes/

Answer (score 2):

I believe you can do this by going to `Tools > Options > Environment > Fonts and Colors`. In there you'll be able to customize about anything.